# Comparing cells from two Excel files

Tags: excel, vba

I have to compare two databases, one from a patient documentation system, and the other from a device database. Both these databases are exported as Excel files.

I want to compare the cells from one column of each Excel file (Column B from the first file, Column M from the second file) and make sure their content is identical.

If it is identical, the cell should turn green, if not, red.

As I don't want to touch the code every time I do this, I made a userform to load the two Excel sheets and click "compare".

How do I compare each cell from these two columns that are in separate Excel files?

I came up with this code, that is executed upon clicking the "compare" button:

```
Sub CommandButton3_Click()

Dim BBraunFile
Dim ICMFile
Dim CellsBBraun
Dim CellsICM
Dim CellA
Dim CellB

Set BBraunFile = Workbooks.Open(strFileToOpenBbraun)
Set ICMFile = Workbooks.Open(strFileToOpenICM)

CellsBBraun = BBraunFile.Worksheets("0_Standard-Pat.-Profil").Range("b4:b5000")
CellsICM = ICMFile.Worksheets("ExternalIDs").Range("M2:M5000")

    For Each CellA In CellsBBraun
        Set CellB = ICMFile.Worksheets("ExternalIDs").Range(Cell.Row, 13)
        If CellA.Value = CellB.Value Then
                CellA.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            Else
                CellA.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        End If
    Next CellA

End Sub
```

I get a runtime error "424: object required".

I looked around, but couldn't find an answer.

Comment: ```CellsBBraun``` and ```CellsICM``` need to have ```set``` before them, they are objects. You will also encounter a problem with ```Range(Cell.Row, 13)```. Cell is not declared anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses a dictionary, you could use any container really but dictionaries have `.exists` which helps here.

You should also declare the type of all your variables, yours are currently all variants.

```
    Dim BBraunFile As Workbook
    Dim ICMFile As Workbook
    Dim CellsBBraun As Range
    Dim CellsICM As Range

    Set BBraunFile = Workbooks.Open(strFileToOpenBbraun)
    Set ICMFile = Workbooks.Open(strFileToOpenICM)

    'Set your objects
    Set CellsBBraun = BBraunFile.Worksheets("0_Standard-Pat.-Profil").Range("b4:b5000")
    Set CellsICM = ICMFile.Worksheets("ExternalIDs").Range("M2:M5000")

    Dim valdict As Object ' This is late binding add in the scripting runtime library for early binding
    Set valdict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") ' This is late binding add in the scripting runtime library for early binding

    Dim CellA As Range

    For Each CellA In CellsICM 'Iterate through workbook we aren't formatting
        valdict(CellA.Value) = "" ' Just populating keys we dont need an item
    Next CellA

    For Each CellA In cellsbbraun 'Iterate through workbook we are formatting
        If valdict.exists(CellA.Value) Then 'See if the value is in the dictionary
            CellA.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        Else
            CellA.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
    Next CellA
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This did the trick. Purely out of interest, this only compares wether a Value exists in the dictionary, right? It doesn't compare specific cells (eg B2 with M2, B3 with M3 and so on)?

Comment: Yeah, just if they were in the other sheet. Comparing B2 to M2 probably wouldn't work unless you can guarantee they are sorted and contain the same number of values. If that is the case you could skip the dictionary and just use the row number to compare each cell.